# How to check if a product is in stock or out stock?

Tags: magento2, reorder

I am trying to override this controller \magento\module-sales\Controller\AbstractController\Reorder.php and would like to add an if statement to check if a product is still in stock or no.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;

/**
 * Abstract class for controllers Reorder(Customer) and Reorder(Guest)
 *
 * @package Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController
 */
abstract class Reorder extends Action\Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface
     */
    protected $orderLoader;

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader,
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Action for reorder
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
            return $result;
        }
        $order = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        /* @var $cart \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart */
        $cart = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart::class);
        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            try {
                $cart->addOrderItem($item);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                if ($this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class)->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($e->getMessage());
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                    $e,
                    __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
                );
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
            }
        }

        $cart->save();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }
}
```

this is the line that I want to add the if statement - basically inside the foreach item function.

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
            try {
                $cart->addOrderItem($item);
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                if ($this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class)->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($e->getMessage());
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                    $e,
                    __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
                );
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
            }
        }
```

What I did:

```
/**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface
     */
    protected $orderLoader;

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    protected $_stockItemRepository;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader,
        Registry $registry,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository
    ) {
        $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Action for reorder
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
            return $result;
        }
        $order = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        /* @var $cart \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart */
        $cart = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart::class);
        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
             $_productStock = $this->_stockItemRepository->get($item->getProductId());
             if($_productStock->getIsInStock()) {
            try {
                
                $cart->addOrderItem($item);
    
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                if ($this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class)->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($e->getMessage());
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                    $e,
                    __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
                );
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
            }
    }
        }

        $cart->save();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }
```

I got this error  `Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Sales\Controller\Order\Reorder\Interceptor` I think it's because of `\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository` contruct

This is a controller for reorder - It keeps on giving me an error, I'm wondering if my code looks correct or no? is there a better a way to do this?

Comment: It is not a good way to solve this problem

Did you run command "php bin/magento setup:di:compile" so that dependency injection knows about it?

Comment: I'm still so new to Magento, what would be a better way to solve this?

Comment: a better approach would be listening to event "adminhtml_customer_orders_add_action_renderer" https://www.magentoextensions.org/documentation/module-sales_2_block_2_adminhtml_2_reorder_2_renderer_2_action_8php_source.html

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about this? I'm still a bit confused. Thank you.

Comment: And why is that the better approach?

Comment: @Magento_learner Please check and update me.

Comment: you can check this into this path vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml  here you see how magento check In stock and Out of stock.

Answer (score 3):

> ***To check product quantity / stock on .phtml***

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/checkstock.phtml**

```
<?php    
$_product = $block->getProduct();
    $productQty = $_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();

    if ($productQty > 0) {
        echo "IN Stock";
        //logic code for instock
    } else {
        echo "Out of Stock";
        //    out of stock logic here
    }
?>
```

***you can add this checkstock.phtml file on the product page***

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
             after="product.info.price" as="checkstock" 
             template="Vendor_Module::product/view/checkstock.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: How can I use this in the controller? Sorry, I am still so new to Magento.

Answer (score -1):

> **You can check using this also**

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderLoaderInterface
     */
    protected $orderLoader;

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    protected $product;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        OrderLoaderInterface $orderLoader,
        Registry $registry,
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->orderLoader = $orderLoader;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context, $orderLoader, $registry);
    }

    /**
     * Action for reorder
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->orderLoader->load($this->_request);
        if ($result instanceof \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface) {
            return $result;
        }
        $order = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

        /* @var $cart \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart */
        $cart = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart::class);
        $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $product_data = $this->product->create()->load($item->getProductId());
            if ($product_data->isAvailable()) {
                try {
                    $cart->addOrderItem($item);
                } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                    if ($this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class)->getUseNotice(true)) {
                        $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($e->getMessage());
                    } else {
                        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                    }
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/history');
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                        $e,
                        __('We can\'t add this item to your shopping cart right now.')
                    );
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
                }
            }
        }
        
        $cart->save();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
    }
```

Comment: you can check this into this path vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml  here you see how magento check In stock and Out of stock.

Comment: how to override abstract class controller?

Comment: and it doesn't work when I ran `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, gives me this error Errors during compilation: Magento\Sales\Controller\Guest\Reorder Missed required argument product in parent::__construct call. File: /vagrant/www/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Guest/Reorder.php